# Converting a CAD/DXF file to a SHP file

Tags: shapefile, dxf, cad

I have a dxf file which was converted from a CAD file. I used QGIS to convert it to a shp file...
This is when I realized that the text associated with the drawing is actually a separate layer...
What I need is one layer where the text is in the attribute table.

What would best the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: I think it would be easier if you would provide a link to your file. DXF is a "spaghetti" format and its quite hard to know how you file is structured without seeing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is quite a bit of missing information in your question.
    Despite that here are some ideas.
1. I will assume your data is polygon. You should attempt to export the cad file as polygon and point files seperately.
The text will be your point file with the label point as the location. and the string value as an attribute.
2. use a spatial join (arcmap term) to join the attributes of the points to the polygons.

Comment: Brad is right text will need to be points (with text attributes) then label them.

Comment: Sorry for the late follow-up.  Been busy with another project...
Took everyone's advice and and suggestions and it turns out that the person who created the CAD file made EVERYTHING a "layer"!!! 
When I exported, found out that some are polygons, poly-lines and text.... 

Had to go back and get a polygon base layer created. Now I have to add the text as attribute data

Thanks Again!!
Chris